# Using fast-csv not reading csv file

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I am trying to first read the CSV file, but I am getting an error saying:

> TypeError: fs.createReadStream is not a function.

Am I doing something wrong? Here is my code:

```
fs.createReadStream('accounts.csv')
    .pipe(csv())
    .on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .on('end', function () {
        console.log('Read finished');
    });
```

Comment: do you have `const fs = require('fs')` or somthing similar in your js file?

Comment: yes i do.  is the csv file need to be in a specific folder?

Comment: Yes, if you don't specify a path node will assume it's in the current directory, however that wouldn't be the cause of your error. if `fs.createReadStream` istn' a function it seems like you haven't imported it correctly

Comment: If the file was in the wrong place your error would be along the lines of `can't find <file>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that i did not have the file inside my project, which is the reason it was not reading it, also, i changed my code to this.

```
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const fs = require('fs');
const fast = require('fast-csv');


    fs.createReadStream('accounts.csv')
        .pipe(csv())
        .on('data', (row) => {
            console.log(row);
        })
        .on('end', () => {
            console.log('CSV file successfully processed');
```