# Reading csv file using node.js

Tags: node.js, csv

I'm trying to read a csv file using node.js. I'm getting the error "unexpected end of input". The following is the code I've used:

```
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const fs = require('fs');
const fast = require('fast-csv');


fs.createReadStream('filename.csv')
.pipe(csv())
.on('data', (row) => {
    console.log(row);
})
.on('end', (row) => {
    console.log('CSV file successfully processed');
```

I've taken the code [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55031113/using-fast-csv-not-reading-csv-file).

when I run the above code in command mode using "node sample.js", the following is the error:

```
C:\Users\learningsql\Desktop\filter>node sample.js
C:\Users\learningsql\Desktop\filter\sample.js:12
    console.log('CSV file successfully processed');


SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
[90m    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:16)[39m
[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:27)[39m
[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)[39m
[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)[39m
[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)[39m
[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47[39m
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I got it. If anyone's curious, I used this code

`const parse = require('csv-parse');
const fs = require('fs');

const csvData= [];

fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/filename.csv')
     .pipe(
         parse({
             delimiter: ','
         })
     )
     .on('data', function (dataRow) {
         csvData.push(dataRow);
     })
     .on('end', function () {
         console.log(csvData);
     });`

Comment: This code is missing the closing brackets from the end `});`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const fs = require('fs');
const fast = require('fast-csv');


    fs.createReadStream('accounts.csv')
        .pipe(csv())
        .on('data', (row) => {
            console.log(row);
        })
        .on('end', () => {
            console.log('CSV file successfully processed')
        });
```

You were missing the closing parentheses and bracket

Comment: thanks. I'm able to read the csv file and get all the columns into arrays, but I need only one specific column's elements as an array. Any suggestions?

Comment: What does "addresses" mean here? Do I replace address_1 with column name of the column I want the records of?

Please refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61769606/creating-dependent-drop-down-filter-using-nodejs) to understand what I'm trying to do.

Thanks for taking time to help me out by the way.

Comment: Correct. Here is the new [link](https://repl.it/@tanya_gupta/ThistleMadApplicationserver) where I have  changed the data set to reflect your particular data set. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. It did work, just had to change the column name in my csv. If there's a space in the column name, apparently it doesn't work. So I changed the **Country Name** header to **CountryName** and it worked!

Comment: Great to hear! Could you accept the answer in that case ?

Comment: I accepted the answer. Since you seem to be knowledgeable about this, could you please help me with this: ||  I'm able to get the two required columns (CountryName and CityName) into two different arrays. I have no idea how to map/link the CountryName with CityName. || For example, when I select Italy in the first dropdown menu, only Italian cities (Milan, Venice, Rome etc) should show up in the second dropdown menu. If I select Spain, only Spanish cities should show up in the dropdown menu (Madrid, Barcelona etc). Any help with this mapping/linking is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please post a question with  the details ?

Comment: Tanya, please [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61769606/creating-dependent-dropdown-menu-filter-using-nodejs) to the question with more details

Comment: Thanks. Stack overflow [discourages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371614/why-isnt-it-good-to-ask-multiple-questions-and-answers-in-one-question)  asking multiple questions at once. May I suggest you break up the questions into a) New question: How do you set up a server using express js 2) Edit existing question to: How do you do dependent dropdowns ? (assuming node.js, express set-up). I have the answer for 1) already and can post it right away. The second, I need to work on.

Comment: I've posted the full answer anyway although moderators might ask you later to split up the question. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, it was helpful. Unfortunately, my project keeps getting more complex as time passes by. Since you're experienced with NodeJS, could you please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62061270/mapping-arrays-from-csv-file-for-tree-hierarchy-visualization-using-nodejs)?