# How to split arrays based on space in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

My array looks like:

```
[P1 Apple, P2 Mango, P2.1 Pluto, P3.1.1 Earth... P10 Red, P10.1 Blue, P10.1.1 Copper]
```

I want to split these based on the space between the elements. For example,

```
In "P1 Apple" - "P1" will be the key, "Apple" will be the value
```

I have to build a tree structure based on the key value. If the key has a whole number (P1, P2, P3, ... P10) then it has to be the child of a root node. I have the root node show up in the visualization already. How can I get this done?

My current code looks like this:

```
filteredSources.forEach(src => {
        console.log("src is " + src)
        let key = src.substring(0, src.indexOf(' '));
        let keyPair = key.split(',');
        console.log("keyPair is " + keyPair + "length is " + keyPair.length)
        for (let i = keyPair.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (i == 0) {
                filteredSources.push({ name: src, key: key, parent: 'Target' });
                console.log("filteredSources is " + filteredSources)
            } else {
                let parentKey = [];
                Object.assign(parentKey, keyPair);
                console.log("parentKey on Object.assign is " + parentKey)
                parentKey.splice(i, 1);
                console.log("parentKey after splice("+i + ",1) is " + parentKey)
                filteredSources.push({ name: src, key: key, parent: parentKey.join('.') });
                console.log("filteredSources is " + filteredSources)
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you clarify what the problem is and what your expected output is supposed to be?  As far as I can see, the obvious error is `key.split(',')` should be `key.split('.')`  and you should be using `slice(0,i)` not `splice`

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62061270/mapping-arrays-from-csv-file-for-tree-hierarchy-visualization-using-nodejs?noredirect=1#comment109837503_62061270) to see the detailed explanation of my problem.

Comment: What are you using for the visualization?  What does the data need to look like for the visualization logic to read it?

Comment: I'm using D3.js for visualization. I think the data from NodeJS needs to be in JSON tree format for D3 to make the tree structure properly. I'm totally new to both NodeJS and D3.

Comment: (in the same row:) what happens if 10.1 doesn't exist for 10.1.1.3?  does ordering matter for 10.1 and 10.2 and 10.3?  will there ever be more than one 11.1.1?

Comment: There can never be 10.1.1.3 without 10.1, since 10.1 will be the parent table for 10.1.1.3 or whatever. The ordering doesn't matter for 10.1, 10.2 and 10.3 as all of these three are children for 10. Only the hierarchy matters, as in root node -> table with whole number  (P10) -> table with one decimal (P10.1) -> table with two decimals (P10.1.1).

Answer (score 0):

Note: your original sample data had missing nodes in the tree hierarchy, which I've filled in manually.
Additional Note: `d3` has functions for parsing CSV data directly that is already in a hierarchical form.

I've transformed the data into the form `{id, parentId, name}` where P3.1.1 will emit `{id: "P3.1.1", parentId: "P3.1", name: "Earth"}`.  This can be fed to `d3.stratify` that will build the hierarchy for you (since d3-tree rendering is your ultimate goal).  I also added a `{id: "P", name: "Target"}` for the root node.
d3-stratify:
https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/blob/master/README.md#stratify
[demo](https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3-stratify)

Trim off `[` `]` and split on `,`, then use RegEx to capture node's path id, node's parent's path's id (which is just the path excluding the last `.[n]`, and the name.
https://regex101.com/r/TvLfQ3/1 to see the regex in action
Finally use `.map` to transform to `{id, parentId, name}` shape.

You could use a recursive function to build a tree, but since you're using d3 you can just let d3-stratify do the work for you.

```js
data = `[P1 Apple, P2 Mango, P2.1 Pluto, P3.1.1 Earth, P10 Red, P10.1 Blue, P10.1.1 Copper, P3 PewPewPew, P3.1 Chopper, P3.2 Twenty, P3.1.2 Two]`
.slice(1,-1).split(', ')
.map(x=>x.match(/^((.*?)(?:\.)?(?:\d*)?) (.*)$/).slice(1))
.map(([id, parentId, name])=>({id, parentId, name}))

data.push({id: 'P', name:'Target'})

console.log(data)
```